# How can I include .less file in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, less

I can include .less file in such way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="<?= $this->basePath('backoffice/less/master.less') ?>">
```

but how can I do this using ZF2, like have done with .css file

```
->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('backoffice/css/style.css'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create this link

```html
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/backoffice/less/master.less">
```

You should be able to do:

```php
->prependStylesheet(array(
    'rel' => 'stylesheet/less',
    'type' => 'text/css',
    'href' => $this->basePath('backoffice/less/master.less')
))
```

Not tested - only theoretically by [looking into code](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/src/Helper/HeadLink.php).